# Spring MVC Tilesを使用した場合、action がNULLになる

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

Spring MVC + Tiles を使用して、WEBアプリを開発しています。
下記のような設定をした場合、formタグのactionが NULL に設定されてしまいました。
コンパイルされている、JSPのファイルを確認したところ、きちんとAction名が設定されている状況です。
また、Spring 3.2.15 + Tiles 2.2.2 で同じように設定した場合は、action名がきちんと設定されました。

ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらアドバイスをお願い致します。

Spring Framework：5.0.8.RELEASE
org.apache.Tiles：3.0.8

**web.xml**

```
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

**bean.xml**

```
   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
     <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
     <property name="redirectHttp10Compatible" value="false" />
   </bean>
   <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
     <property name="definitions">
       <list>
         <value>/WEB-INF/tiles_common.xml</value>
       </list>
     </property>
   </bean>
```

**JSP**

```
<form:form modelAttribute="loginModel" action="login.html" autocomplete="off" id="loginModel" method="POST">
```

**html**

```
<form id="loginModel" action="null" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
```

**login_jsp.java**

```
   _jspx_th_form_005fform_005f0.setPageContext(_jspx_page_context);
   _jspx_th_form_005fform_005f0.setParent(null);
   // /WEB-INF/views/login/login.jsp(2,0) name = modelAttribute type = null reqTime = true required = false fragment = false deferredValue = false expectedTypeName = null deferredMethod = false methodSignature = null
   _jspx_th_form_005fform_005f0.setModelAttribute("loginModel");
   // /WEB-INF/views/login/login.jsp(2,0) name = action type = null reqTime = true required = false fragment = false deferredValue = false expectedTypeName = null deferredMethod = false methodSignature = null
   _jspx_th_form_005fform_005f0.setAction("login.html");
   // /WEB-INF/views/login/login.jsp(2,0) name = autocomplete type = null reqTime = true required = false fragment = false deferredValue = false expectedTypeName = null deferredMethod = false methodSignature = null
   _jspx_th_form_005fform_005f0.setAutocomplete("off");
   // /WEB-INF/views/login/login.jsp(2,0) name = id type = null reqTime = true required = false fragment = false deferredValue = false expectedTypeName = null deferredMethod = false methodSignature = null
   _jspx_th_form_005fform_005f0.setId("loginModel");
   // /WEB-INF/views/login/login.jsp(2,0) name = method type = null reqTime = true required = false fragment = false deferredValue = false expectedTypeName = null deferredMethod = false methodSignature = null
   _jspx_th_form_005fform_005f0.setMethod("POST");
```

Answer (score 0):

現象が解決しました。

RequestDataValueProcessorを使用していたのですが、
processActionメソッドで、nullを設定していました。

同じような事象の回答も見つけました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647285/action-name-is-null-in-spring-4-mvc